# Add an undefined method promise to an array to be resolved later in Promise.all()

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vue.js, promise, pouchdb

I want to queue up DB calls that will be executed once it's connected. The DB object is created and stored as a member of a module when it's connected.

DB Module:

```html
var db = {
  localDb: null,
  connectLocal: (dbName) => {
    // Do stuff
    this.localDb = new PouchDB(dbName) // has a allDocs() method
  }
}
```

Adding calls to queue:

```html
var dbQueue = []

function getDocs () {
  dbQueue.push (
    db.localDb.allDocs () // allDocs() not yet defined; returns promise
  )
}

// Called when connected and queue is not empty:
function processQueue () {
  Promise.all (dbQueue)
  .then(...)
}
```

If getDocs() is called before db.connectLocal() sets db.localDb, then I get the following error (or similar) because db.localDb is not yet defined:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Is it possible to add an undefined method, that returns a promise, to an array to be resolved later in Promise.all()?  Any other ideas as to how I can solve this issue?

Also, I'm using Vue.js and PouchDB.

Comment: Why is `getDocs()` even called before `connectLocal()`? I think that's the real issue that you need to solve.

Comment: I don't get what your queue is doing or how it is supposed to work (but I have the suspicion that it doesn't actually work). Can you please elaborate what you need the queue for and where (by whom) the `getDocs` and `processQueue` functions are called?

Comment: @Bergi, `getDocs()` is called in multiple Vue components for various reasons - one component calls it in `mount()`, another after an `onclick` event.  I could check to see if connection is established for every DB call, but that'd be a lot, and I'd still need a way to call it again once the connection is made.

Comment: @Bergi, the queue holds DB calls that'll be processed once the DB is connected.  It does work, but it doesn't in this instance because I'm adding a promise that's not yet defined.  It's one of many potential DB calls that are made from Vue.js components.  I could have left the whole queue part out of my question, because it's not the problem, but I felt like it helped illustrate my problem.

Comment: The queue part is really important, thanks for mentioning it. It sounds like you call `processQueue` immediately after connecting, and don't do much else with the array structure. I would then suggest to drop the array and use a promise for the database connection to which you queue on, quite like in Marius' answer below. How to best initialise this promise would however depend on how and where `connectLocal` is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my queue issue, but it wasn't at all how I was trying to go about it.

My first problem was thinking that Promise.all() deferred calling my methods until it was called, but they are called when added to the array.  This caused the error I mentioned in my question.  So I needed to rethink how to populate the queue with methods that may not yet exist.

The solution was to add the calls to an array (the queue) as strings (e.g. `"getDocs"`), then loop through the array calling the methods using [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) (e.g. `db["getDocs"]()`).

My app is written in Vue.js so it's obviously different, but here's a simplified, working example:

```
// Dummy DB object
var db = {
  docs: [1, 2, 3]
};

// Queue were the DB ops are stored
var dbQueue = [];

// Process the queue - called elsewhere once the DB is connected
// The processed array and Promise.all() aren't necessary as you could just call
// the method outright, but I want to log the results in order
async function processQueue() {
  var processed = []; // Called queue methods

  // Add valid methods to
  dbQueue.forEach(method => {
    if (typeof db[method] === "function") {
      return processed.push(db[method]());
    } else {
      console.error(`"${method}" is not a name of a valid method.`);
    }
  });

    // Log promise results
  await Promise.all(processed).then(res => {
    console.log("Processed:", res);
  });

  // Empty the queue
  dbQueue = [];
}

// Add some calls to the queue of methods that don't yet exist
dbQueue.push("getDocs");
dbQueue.push("getDocs");

// Simulate adding the method
db.getDocs = function() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(this.docs);
  });
};

// Process queue once conditions are met (e.g. db is connected); called elsewhere
processQueue();
```

And here's a fiddle with an example that allows arguments for the methods: https://jsfiddle.net/rjbv0284/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can make a promise in your db module instead of just `localDb` property:

```
let localDb = null;
let resolveLocalDb = null;
let localDbPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolveLocalDb = resolve;
});

var db = {
  getLocalDb: () {
    return localDbPromise;
  }
  connectLocal: (dbName) => {
    // Do stuff
    localDb = new PouchDB(dbName) // has a allDocs() method
    resolveLocalDb(localDb);
  }
}
```

Then, exchange `.localDb` to `getLocalDb()`, which returns a promise.

```
dbQueue.push(
  db.getLocalDb().then(db => db.allDocs())
)
```

Comment: You might just want to make the property hold the promise itself, not a getter method. Also you don't need the `localDb` local variable - everyone using the database would access the value through the promise anyway.